# how to set the background image in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

I am implementing a carousel.

https://splidejs.com/
https://github.com/Splidejs/splide

**I want to set background image on div when it come to view.** In other words I want to fetch image not when application run .But I want to fetch image when that div come in view .And set that image on background.

is it possible ?

Here is my  code

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-solomon-mcy4y?file=/src/index.js:0-92
I tried like this

```
import Splide from "@splidejs/splide";
new Splide("#splide", {
  lazyLoad: true
}).mount();
```

in my case image download when application run. on lazy loaded. I want it only download when it come to view and set the background.